# Select item by data-id in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an applescript program that executes javascript in Google Chrome's front browser tab.

Whenever my script is run, I need to select the element with data-id `play-pause` and `.click` it. I cannot use jQuery as it's not included with the document.

Is there a way in **pure javascript** that I can do this?

(I'm sure there's probably a way to import it so I could use it but I'm not going down that path for a simple program.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From IE8 and up you can use `querySelector`, or `querySelectorAll` if there's more than one element

```
document.querySelector('[data-id="play-pause"]').click();
```